# Are holidays included by default in SharePoint 2013 calendar?

Tags: sharepoint

Can some one tell me if public holidays are included by default in SharePoint 2013 calendar? If not how can I add the (UK) public holidays to the calendar so that whenever user visit the calendar, s/he will be able to see them inside the calendar.

Comment: Public holidays vary by country, so you might need to specify what country you want public holidays for? This doesn't belong on Stack Overflow anyway, since it is not a programming question.

Comment: I need to add UK holidays  to Calendar ,once user set he would be available on holiday n after specifying timings he would be available ,i need to set all the holidays in recurrence  make him available ,how can i implement these?would u help me out

Answer (score 0):

Holidays will not be there by default. However, you can just click on the calendar and add an entry by using "Add" and giving the name of the holiday as the "Title" and marking this as an all day event.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c1uT.png)

Comment: how can i able to set holiday in calendar pro grammatically?

Comment: What type of program? PowerShell, JavaScript, Client side C#, Server side c#? Adding a item in a calendar is same as adding an item in a list.

Comment: using server side c#,while adding list am getting error as The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: value (9c57ec9d-e997-50ae-19ab-65f27f41ac19)

Comment: how to add holiday as recurring event ?

Comment: Can you at least post what code you have written? If you want a recurring event then how often does it recur?

Comment: string recWeekends = "<recurrence><rule> " +
                                    "<firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek> " +
                                    "<repeat><weekly ho='TRUE' weekFrequency='1' /></repeat> " +
                                    "<repeatForever>TRUE</repeatForever> " +
                                    "</rule></recurrence>";

Comment: i want that recur to happen from the today to entireyear ?

Comment: @ManjulaG: would you post that code in the question please? A formatting tool is available.